# Multidimensional form array with Vuejs and Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, multidimensional-array, laravel-5, vue.js

I am posting an array of form data using VueJs, this is what it looks like:

```
hives: [{
    hive_type_id: '',
    quantity: '',
    yard_id: this.yardId,
    action: 'added',
    added_from: '',
    converted_to: '',
    notes: '',
    logged_at: moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY'),
}]
```

1) How do I access this in my controller to store to the DB?
I have tried, using a foreach:

```
foreach($request->get('hives') as $key => $val) { ... }
```

And then accessing each individual hive data:
e.g.

```
$request->action[$key]
$request->added_from[$key]
```

But am having no luck storing to the DB.

2) How would I validate this array using a Form Request?

Thanks for you help!

Comment: Does the foreach work correctly?

Comment: What does "having no luck storing to the DB" mean?  Are you getting an error?  What does your DB code look like?  What DB are you using?

Comment: The foreach seems to work correctly, I think the issue is when I am trying to access the individual hive nodes, is this the correct way: '$request->action[$key]'?

Comment: DB is Postgres but have been saving to that fine prior to the data being an array.

Comment: DB code: 
`$new_hive = new Hive;
                    $new_hive->yard_id = $yard->id;
                    $new_hive->hive_type_id = $request->hive_type[$key];
                    $new_hive->total = $request->quantity[$key];
                    $new_hive->quantity = $request->quantity[$key];
                    $new_hive->action = $request->action[$key];
                    $new_hive->notes = $request->notes[$key];
                    $new_hive->logged_at = $request->logged_at[$key];
                    $new_hive->active = true;
                    $new_hive->save();`

Comment: And this is what the data looks like from VueJs:
`[ { "hive_type_id": "1", "quantity": "", "yard_id": 1, "action": "added", "added_from": "", "converted_to": "", "notes": "", "logged_at": "04-10-2016" }, { "hive_type_id": "3", "quantity": "5", "yard_id": 1, "action": "stocktake", "added_from": "", "converted_to": "", "notes": "", "logged_at": "04-10-2016" } ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can drop the `$key` and give a more meaningful name to `$val`. Just access it directly, like this:

```
foreach ($request->get('hives') as $hive) {
    $new_hive = new Hive;
    $new_hive->quantity = $hive->quantity;
    $new_hive->action   = $hive->action;
}
```

Form Request validation is well covered in the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#form-request-validation